# Kill the running command when expected output is met

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a command which will do some activity will display message on screen that contains word "continue".
As soon as that word is found, I want to kill that command. I tried below syntax but it is not working.

```
Command_to_run >> "logfile" 2>&1 &    
    pid=$!
        while ! grep -q "continue"  "$logfile" ; 
         do
           sleep 1
         done
kill -$pid
```

Comment: Actually my script includes kill $pid after while loop, but its not working, any working/aleternate way to do this                                                       
     Command_to_run >> "logfile" 2>&1 &    
    pid=$!
        while ! grep -q "continue"  "$logfile" ; 
         do
           sleep 1
         done       kill -$pid

Comment: It would help to know what "is not working".   Does it give a syntax error?  Does it output an error message (and if so what message)?  Does it fail to try to kill the `Command_to_run`?  Does it try but fail to kill `Command_to_run`?

Comment: One reason why the code doesn't work is that command output is sent to a file called `logfile` but `grep` is run on a file called `$logfile`.  That won't work unless the variable `logfile` has been set to the string `logfile` elsewhere.  [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds this problem.  [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds many common problems in shell code.  Its reports contain links to detailed information about problems, including how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: @pjh: You are correct, OP's code is almost working, at least with the sample command from my answer. I believe the cause of the confusion was the negative PID number without the end of options `--` in the `kill` command that gives `invalid signal specification` error.

Answer (score 2):

One method would be to have `command_to_run` redirect the output to a pipe, and have the pipe closed as soon as the requested output appears in the output.

When the standard output is closed, most commands will exit as soon as they try to write something new to stdout.

Here is an example of how this could be achieved:

File `command_to_run`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo start
seq 2 
echo continue
seq 10
echo end
```

```bash
$ ./command_to_run | tee logfile | awk '1;/continue/{exit}'
start
1
2
continue
```

Alternatively, if you don't need the output to appear in stdout, you can use `grep`:

```bash
./command_to_run | tee logfile | grep -q continue

$ cat logfile 
start
1
2
continue
```

---

It's worth mentioning that the code in the OP almost works as well, it just needs some minor tweaks:

- remove the dollar sign from `logfile` in the `grep` command to match the name that is used above
- Use redirection without append to `logfile` so that `continue` string is not present from previous execution
- add the end-of-options modifier `--` in the kill command so that the negative PID (group) is not evaluated as a signal number.

```bash
./command_to_run > "logfile" 2>&1 &    
pid=$!
while ! grep -q "continue"  "logfile" ; 
do
  sleep 1
done
kill -- -$pid
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `coproc` for that

```
#! /bin/bash

coproc ./command_to_run
until [[ $line =~ continue ]]; do
    read -r -u ${COPROC[0]} line
done
kill $COPROC_PID
```

if you really want the log file you can write to it inside the loop.